# What is the "subIterable" method for a Xodus property?

Tags: java, xodus

I have this custom property type:

```
public class EmbeddedEntityIterable implements Serializable, ByteIterable {
  
  @NotNull
  @Override
  public ByteIterable subIterable(int offset, int length) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(@NotNull ByteIterable o) {
    return 0;
  }

}
```

How does Xodus use `subIterable` and `compareTo`? Is it safe just to return a NULL value on a `@NotNull` method? This `EmbeddedEntityIterable`  is basically a `Map<String,Comparable>` under the hood, that is also a representation of a very nested JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not safe to return `null`, and you have to implement non-trivial `compareTo`. Otherwise you won't be able to use your `ByteIterable` as a key (with Stores of any type) and value (with Stores that can have key duplicates). If you use EntityStores API and your `ByteIterable` as a property value, then you definitely have to implement the methods, since the `ByteIterable` would be used under the hood as a key in a property value index.

For custom implementations of `ByteIterable`, it's prefereble to inherit from [ByteIterableBase abstract class](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/blob/master/openAPI/src/main/java/jetbrains/exodus/ByteIterableBase.java) which has basic implementations of the methods.

In addtiton, if you define custom property type then you must define order to support out-of-the-box features like sorting, searching for a value or searching in a range of values. If you don't need these features then probably it makes sense to save such data in blobs or blob strings instead of properties.